# "Ну что тут еще скажешь... Мастер!" Мастер — постпозитивный номинатив?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

> "Ну что тут еще скажешь... Мастер!"

Мастер — постпозитивный номинатив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что оценочное значение имеет **вся фраза**: *Ну **что** тут еще скажешь... Мастер!*

Но второе предложение скорее **неполное**. Его полный текст восстанавливается по  первому предложению, например: *Я могу сказать (что?) только одно: "Мастер!".*

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд, нет. Именительный падеж использован в функции сказуемого двусоставного предложения, вторая часть которого - неполное предложение. Пунктуация и прописная буква как бы разбивает его на два предложения, но это особенность передачи разговорной речи. Если дополнить подлежащим, станет ясно:

```
Ну что еще скажешь: [ты] - мастер.
```

Теперь хорошо видна функция сказуемого.